# Proof: Ratio of Cauchy distribution

Tags: mathematica-online

I have a problem that I have been struggling to prove.
Can someone help me with proving this following question, please ? :
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Because you want a "proof" you should ask this at either https://stats.stackexchange.com or https://math.stackexchange.com/.  You might also show what you've tried so far at either of those sites as you'll get a better reception.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[σ[x_]] := Subscript[σ, x]

distBN = BinormalDistribution[{σ[U], σ[V]}, ρ];
```

Note that
[image]

```
distMN = MultinormalDistribution[{{σ[U]^2, ρ σ[U]*σ[V]}, 
    {ρ*σ[U]*σ[V], σ[V]^2}}];

PDF[distBN, {u, v}] == PDF[distMN, {u, v}] // 
 Simplify[#, {σ[U] > 0, σ[V] > 0}] &

(* True *)

PDF[TransformedDistribution[U/V, {U, V} \[Distributed] distBN], z]
```

[image]

```
PDF[TransformedDistribution[U/V, {U, V} \[Distributed] distBN], z] == 
  PDF[TransformedDistribution[U/V, {U, V} \[Distributed] distMN], z] //
  Simplify[#, {σ[U] > 0, σ[V] > 0}] &

(* True *)

distC = CauchyDistribution[ρ σ[U]/σ[V], 
   Sqrt[1 - ρ^2]*σ[U]/σ[V]];

PDF[distC, z] // Simplify
```

[image]

```
PDF[TransformedDistribution[U/V, {U, V} \[Distributed] distBN], z] == 
  PDF[distC, z] // Simplify

(* True *)
```